# React composition component proptypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm using the composition pattern for react. So, for example, I have this simple component:

```
class Simple extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

Simple.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Now, I have this enhanced component:

```
class Enhanced extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Hi, I'm the enhanced version</div>
        <Simple {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, how can I specify the proptypes for the enhanced component? I could do this:

```
Enhanced.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

but that's not good because I'll have to list all the props of `Simple` component and anytime I change those props, I'll have to change them in `Enhanced`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`propTypes` are just normal JS objects. You can compose them however you like:

```
// Simple.js
export const simplePropTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

Simple.propTypes = simplePropTypes

// Enhanced.js
import Simple, { simplePropTypes } from './Simple'

Enhanced.propTypes = {
  somethingElse: React.PropTypes.number,
  ...simplePropTypes
}
```

**update**:

You *should* be able to use the component definition's `propTypes` directly.

```
Enhanced.propTypes = {
  somethingElse: React.PropTypes.number,
  ...Simple.propTypes
}
```

Comment: For the updated answer, is that an es7 feature? Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Destructuring the propTypes directly off the Component doesn't work for me either. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: You cannot use spread operator for props because eslint won't recognize them. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2195